# Why is using the structure variable itself in its element not allowed?

Tags: c++, c, struct

Why declaring a structure with its own identifier as an element of it is not allowed? where as a self referential structure  which is declared by the same variable of the struct with a pointer symbol!

this is the code I tried out:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    struct am
    {
     int a;
     struct am k; // this reported an error
    };
```

This code reported me a error where as when i used it as a pointer it accepted it , i searched the web and i came to know that it was called the self referential structure

```
#include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    struct ko
    {
     int a;
     struct ko * op; // this was allowed by my compiler
    };
```

this structure worked please brief me !

I'm using a TurboC++ version 3.0 by borland international inc.

Comment: That would cause an infinite loop!

Comment: @BennoZeeman More like infinite recursion

Comment: Think about it, compute the size of am, which contains itself.

Comment: no I'm asking that why a self referential structure is allowed where as a structure with its own variable declaration is not allowed something like this               struct ko { struct ko l; }; why is this not allowed?

Comment: Try placing a 2'x 2'x 2' box inside a similar 2' x 2' x 2' box that's inside another box and so on. That's what you're trying to do in the first example. It can't work. But you can take a 2' x 2' x 2' box and place a note inside it where you write the location of another box. That's what you're doing in the 2. example with a pointer.

Comment: Thank you nos i get what you're trying to say and sorry if this post was done before im just a beginner

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An object cannot contain an object of the same type as itself; that's a logical impossibililty, as it would need to be larger than itself.

As you say, it could contain a pointer or reference, but not an object.

> I'm using a TurboC++ version 3.0 by borland international inc.

I've no idea why you'd use a twenty-year old compiler, and an ancient dialect of C++ that few now remember. But this was just as impossible then as it is now.

Comment: *I've no idea why you'd use a twenty-year old compiler*, statistically speaking, his teacher probably told him to use it.

Comment: it's not even standard C++

Comment: our syllabus includes only these and not the modern ones. sorry to have them

Comment: @SathyaNarayanan: I'd drop the course then. It will only waste your time. If you still want to learn C++, teach yourself with a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242).

Comment: advise me a book then

Comment: @SathyaNarayanan: I did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons:

1. The `struct am` type isn't *complete* until the closing `}` of the struct definition; when you try to declare `k` as an instance of `struct am`, the compiler still doesn't know how big `struct am` needs to be.
2. A struct cannot contain an *instance* of itself, since that member would also have to contain an instance of itself, which would contain an instance of itself, *ad inifinitum*; the resulting object would be inifinitely large.

A struct can contain a *pointer* to an instance of the same type because a) you can create pointers to incomplete types, and b) all struct pointer types have the same size and representation.